# Reading Specific text from a website

Tags: c#, html, xpath, html-agility-pack

I am trying to make a database, but i need to get info from a website. Mainly the Title, Date, Length and Genre from the IMDB website. I have tried like 50 different things and it is just not working. 
Here is my code.

```
    public string GetName(string URL)
{       
    HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
    HtmlDocument doc = web.Load(URL);

    var Attr = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@id=\"overview - top\"]/h1/span[1]@itemprop")[0];

    return Name;
}
```

When I run this it just gives me a XPathException. I just want it to return the Title of a movie. I am now just using this movie for a example and testing but, I want it to work with all movies http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0405422
I am using the HtmlAgilityPack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last bit of your XPath is not valid. Also to get only single element from `HtmlDocument()` you can use `SelectSingleNode()` instead of `SelectNodes()` :

```
HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
HtmlDocument doc = web.Load("http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0405422/");

var xpath = "//*[@id='overview-top']/h1/span[@class='itemprop']";
var span = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode(xpath);
var title = span.InnerText;

Console.WriteLine(title);
```

**output :**

```
The 40-Year-Old Virgin
```

**demo link :** *

https://dotnetfiddle.net/P7U5A7

*) the demo shows that the correct title is printed, along with an error specific to .NET Fiddle (you can safely ignore the error).

Comment: Thanks so much i have been strugeling for the last 2 days

Comment: Could you maby also help me with the release date and picture?

Comment: @kevindt12 Now you have a working example on your hand. The only part needed to be changed to get the other data i.e release date and picture is the `xpath`. Try again a bit by yourself with help of the internet.

Comment: @kevindt12 Later -not necessarily 2 days later :) - if you still can't get the correct result, post a new question showing the XPath you've tried, and I  will be more than happy to help

Comment: Okay i will but the formating is diffrent for those 2 thing and i dont know anything about XPath but i will try

Comment: @kevindt12 not the most trustful source, but giving you a concise and relatively easy to understand introduction to XPath : http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_syntax.asp

Comment: Okay Thanks i think learning i bit about xpath is quite handy

Comment: @kevindt12 last thing, if you wanna play around with the XPath syntax you just learned : http://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html (there are many other xpath tester online though)

Answer (score 0):

I making something familiar and this is my code which gets info from imdb.com website.:

```
string html = getUrlData(imdbUrl + "combined");
            Id = match(@"<link rel=""canonical"" href=""http://www.imdb.com/title/(tt\d{7})/combined"" />", html);
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Id))
            {
                status = true;
                Title = match(@"<title>(IMDb \- )*(.*?) \(.*?</title>", html, 2);
                OriginalTitle = match(@"title-extra"">(.*?)<", html);
                Year = match(@"<title>.*?\(.*?(\d{4}).*?\).*?</title>", html);
                Rating = match(@"<b>(\d.\d)/10</b>", html);
                Genres = matchAll(@"<a.*?>(.*?)</a>", match(@"Genre.?:(.*?)(</div>|See more)", html));
                Directors = matchAll(@"<td valign=""top""><a.*?href=""/name/.*?/"">(.*?)</a>", match(@"Directed by</a></h5>(.*?)</table>", html));
                Cast = matchAll(@"<td class=""nm""><a.*?href=""/name/.*?/"".*?>(.*?)</a>", match(@"<h3>Cast</h3>(.*?)</table>", html));
                Plot = match(@"Plot:</h5>.*?<div class=""info-content"">(.*?)(<a|</div)", html);
                Runtime = match(@"Runtime:</h5><div class=""info-content"">(\d{1,4}) min[\s]*.*?</div>", html);
                Languages = matchAll(@"<a.*?>(.*?)</a>", match(@"Language.?:(.*?)(</div>|>.?and )", html));
                Countries = matchAll(@"<a.*?>(.*?)</a>", match(@"Country:(.*?)(</div>|>.?and )", html));
                Poster = match(@"<div class=""photo"">.*?<a name=""poster"".*?><img.*?src=""(.*?)"".*?</div>", html);
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Poster) && Poster.IndexOf("media-imdb.com") > 0)
                {
                    Poster = Regex.Replace(Poster, @"_V1.*?.jpg", "_V1._SY200.jpg");
                    PosterLarge = Regex.Replace(Poster, @"_V1.*?.jpg", "_V1._SY500.jpg");
                    PosterFull = Regex.Replace(Poster, @"_V1.*?.jpg", "_V1._SY0.jpg");
                }
                else
                {
                    Poster = string.Empty;
                    PosterLarge = string.Empty;
                    PosterFull = string.Empty;
                }
                ImdbURL = "http://www.imdb.com/title/" + Id + "/";
                if (GetExtraInfo)
                {
                    string plotHtml = getUrlData(imdbUrl + "plotsummary");
                }

//Match single instance
    private string match(string regex, string html, int i = 1)
    {
        return new Regex(regex, RegexOptions.Multiline).Match(html).Groups[i].Value.Trim();
    }

    //Match all instances and return as ArrayList
    private ArrayList matchAll(string regex, string html, int i = 1)
    {
        ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
        foreach (Match m in new Regex(regex, RegexOptions.Multiline).Matches(html))
            list.Add(m.Groups[i].Value.Trim());
        return list;
    }
```

Maybe you will find something useful

Comment: Looks intresting i dont understand hafe of it but intresting. I am new and practising C#

Comment: I have donwloaded this class: http://web3o.blogspot.de/2010/11/aspnetc-imdb-scraping-api.html and and slightly edited to suit me.